# How to pass API response as @Input parameter in angular 6 component

Tags: angular, api, angular6

I have two components as "new" and "history". history component is called inside "new" component as follows,

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <app-leave-history [LeaveData]="ldata" [RoleData]="permission"></app-leave- history>
</div>
```

above is inside "new" component. i need to pass data to 'ldata' property from "new" component ts file. when i pass data to 'ldata' with API response, component doesn't get data. because before the API response, history component get loaded. should i call the API inside the history component or is there any way to call API from my "new" component and pass to 'ldata'?

Comment: why did you remove the answer?

Comment: i added the answer at the below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*ngIf` to wait for the API call to get complete and initialize `ldata`. Angular will wait for it and then only render `app-leave-history`

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
   <app-leave-history 
     *ngIf="ldata && permission" 
     [LeaveData]="ldata" 
     [RoleData]="permission">
   </app-leave-history>
</div>
```

**Suggestion:** Please consider renaming `ldata`, `LeaveData` and `RoleData` to `camelCase` i.e. `lData`(or `leaveData` to be clearer), `leaveData` and `roleData`. This is something that [**Angular StyleGuide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-04) Suggests:

> Do use lower camel case to name properties and methods.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 2):

As @SiddAjmera & @Sajeetharan suggested *ngIf part added and additionally i assigned the response in ngOnChanges() event. Now it works !!!

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are doing is correct, you make the API call in the new component and assign the response.

Pass the response as a input to the new component. Inorder to pass the data once it is recieve you can render the history component using `*ngIf`

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <app-leave-history *ngIf="ldata && permission" [LeaveData]="ldata" [RoleData]="permission"></app-leave- history>
 </div>
```